# Как игнорировать файлы только в локальном репозитории?

Tags: git, gitignore

Я храню в рабочей папке проекта файлы, которые не подлежат контролю версий (например, фотографии котиков). Хотел бы их игнорировать. Но для этого требуется изменить .gitignore, который общий на всех разработчиков. Этого я делать не могу или не хочу (например, чтобы не выдавать котиков).

Можно ли как-то настроить игнорирование только для своего репозитория?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1753070/5000805

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Да, это возможно с помощью настройки файла `.git/info/exclude`. Он устроен точно так же, как обычный `.gitignore`, но не включается в состав коммита, и поэтому не передается с командами `clone`, `push`, `pull`.

```
$ open .git/info/exclude

#hide my cats
cats/
```

Или одним действием:

```
echo -e '\n#hide my cats\ncats'>>.git/info/exclude
```

Comment: `echo '*'>cats/.gitignore`

Comment: @PetSerAl кстати, можно и так.

Answer (score 4):

Еще можно выполнить команду, после которой гит перестает следить за изменениями в `youfilename` локально:

```
   git update-index --assume-unchanged youfilename
```

Чтобы отменить данное действие можно выполнить:

```
   git update-index --no-assume-unchanged youfilename
```