# Как убрать файл конфигурации Tomcat из-под контроля версий

Tags: java, git, tomcat

Склонировал проект, там есть файл (назовем его файл1) конфигурации который мне нужно поправить под себя.

Это приложение на Java Spring, предлагается использовать Tomcat и править $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/*.xml, но я запускаю с idea через tomcat + артефакт.

Файл уже отслеживается, я добавил его в `.git/info/exclude` и теперь он числится как deleted. Закоммитил изменения в свой репо, возможно уже тут я начал совершать ошибку.

Сделал отдельную ветку в которой буду делать работу, сделал изменения (назовем их файл2) нужных мне файлов, закоммитил и отправил ветку на гитхаб. Захожу на гитхабе в ветку с изменениями, жму pull request и вижу там на отправу файл1 и файл2.

Как мне в pull request отправлять только файл2?

Comment: Добавил меток, надеюсь что набегут эксперты-джависты и расскажут, как они борются со своими конфигами. )

Comment: Связанный более общий вопрос: [git и конфигурационные файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416219/git-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

Answer (score 4):

> Как мне в pull request отправлять только файл2

#### Разово решить проблему, восстановив файл

В пулл-реквест предлагаются не файлы, туда предлагается некоторая ветка (а по сути — коммит, на который эта ветка указывает). В вашей ветке этот файл конфигурации поменялся по сравнению с оригинальной — придётся откатить это изменение. Как-то так:

```
# копируем свой конфиг куда-нибудь рядом
cp foobar.conf foobar.conf.bak

# достаём версию конфига из стабильной ветки
git checkout origin/master -- foobar.conf

# добавляем в индекс и коммитим
git add foobar.conf
git commit -m'restore configuration'

# отправляем изменения в ветку, обновляя пулл-реквест
git push

# возвращаем свой рабочий конфиг
rm foobar.conf
mv foobar.conf.bak  foobar.conf
```

#### Оставить файл, но перестать фиксировать будущие изменения (не выйдет)

Для того, чтобы вовсе убрать этот файл из-под контроля версий, придётся сделать две вещи:

1. Добавить его в .gitignore [или ./git/info/exclude](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448215/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8)
2. Сообщить git об удалении файла: `git rm --cached foobar.conf`.

Но при этом ваша ветка и создаваемый из неё пулл-реквест будут содержать в себе *удаление файла*, так что перед мержем в общую ветку всё равно придётся возвращать файл.

#### Решить проблему в корне

Версионирование конфигурационных файлов часто является нетривиальной задачей. Нужно одновременно хранить и версионировать некую дефолтную конфигурацию и при этом позволять разработчикам иметь произвольные конфиги на своей машине. Если приложение серверное, всё ещё более усложняется.

Ваши затруднения вызваны тем, что в проекте, с которым вы работаете, эта задача не решена. Возможно, вы сможете предложить решение и избавить себя и коллег от необходимости каждый раз жонглировать горящими <s>факелами</s> конфигами.

По моему опыту, хорошо работает такая модель:

- Репозиторий не содержит сами конфигурационные файлы. Вместо них:

  - Либо образцы файлов типа `foobar.conf.example`. Вы копируете их и получаете `foobar.conf`.
  - Либо инструмент для генерации файлов — это может быть отдельный скрипт (какой-нибудь `configure.sh` или `configure.bat`), параметр запуска приложения, система сборки (maven,  ant...) или система управления конфигурациями (Ansible, Saltstack, Puppet, Chef).
- Эти образцы или инструмент генерации можно и нужно версионировать.
- А сами файлы конфигурации на своей машине вы меняете как вам нужно и никогда не добавляете в контроль версий.
- Чтобы помочь вам случайно их не закоммитить, в `.gitignore` все эти файлы перечисляются буквально или описываются некой маской вроде `*.conf`.

Comment: Но в данном частном случае файл конфиг уже под контролем, со стороны владельца репозитория предлагается производить кофигуюцию на стороне веб сервера, я же запускаю проект через IDE что удобно для дебага, по этому вынужден править этот файл. Отктатить коммит не проблема, как дальше править файл1 что бы он не попадал под дальнейший контроль? Править .gitignore я тоже не могу, он так же полетить в общий репо, для этого я использовал exclude.

Comment: @SergeiR вот такое неудобное решение в этом проекте. Вы можете просто стараться никогда не коммитить свой конфиг. Но как только он поменяется в основном репозитории, у вас просто `git pull` не получится из-за конфликта (там и там есть изменения относительно общего предка).

Comment: @SergeiR а расскажиет чуть подробнее, какого типа приложение, какие технологии используются?

Comment: Это приложение на Java Spring, предлагается использовать Tomcat и править $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/*.xml, но я запускаю с idea через tomcat + артифакт.

Comment: @SergeiR `как дальше править файл1 что бы он не попадал под дальнейший контроль` – к сожалению, идеального решения нет. Можно только править, но не добавлять.

Comment: надо бы, наверно, какой-то суммирующий вопросо-ответ сделать по поводу того, как поступать с локальными конфигурационными данными в контексте контроля версий. есть пара свеженьких кандидатов в дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/668483/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/668125/178576)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin согласен, такой вопрос был бы полезен. Меня останавливает то, что я вообще далеко не эксперт по бэкендам и развертыванию.