# Разные локальные версии файлов в GIT

Tags: git, bitbucket

Разработка ведется двумя разработчиками через репозиторий на `BitBucket`.
Есть несколько строк в файле, отличающихся среди разработчиков `#define` как игнорировать при `pull`, потом `merge` c локальной веткой, именно этот файл но при этом, что-бы локально эти файлы отслеживались.
Точней при merge автоматически говорить гиту брать локальную версию. Всегда.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/611870/178576

Comment: Так понял что нет готового "красивого " решения. Писать отдельную программку которая бы меняла значение #define на мои?  Нет ли в системе гит возможности помечать куски кода тегами, которые потом учитываются при merge? Или есть другие способы это реализовать как-то?

Comment: есть готовое решение, оно изложено по приведённой ссылке. выносите локальные настройки в отдельный файл, который не включаете в контроль версий.