# добавление настроек и базы данных в проект на гитхабе

Tags: django, git, github

Я делаю проект на джанго и рассказывать всем где у меня лежит файл с базой данных и оригинальный файл с настройками, естественно, не хочется. Но при этом хотелось бы добавить какую-нибудь пустую базу данных и тестовый файл с настройками, чтобы каждый мог запустить мой проект.

Для этого я прописал путь к файлу с оригинальными настройками в переменной `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`, и добавил этот файл в `.git/info/execude` (с базой данных то же самое). Затем создал тестовый файл с настройками и пустыми данными и запушил их на гитхаб, чтобы они были доступны всем.

Но получается так, что когда кто-нибудь пушит мне свои изменения, то вместе с ними пушит и настройки и базу данных.

Как сделать так, чтобы этого не происходило? Попробовал добавить эти два файла в `.gitignore`, но всё равно изменения от других людей приходят и мне. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выйти из данной ситуации?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/611870/178576

Comment: `execude` – вы ведь имели в виду `exclude`?

Comment: Настройки нужно разделять на общие (их положить в репозиторий) и локальные (их в репозиторий не ложить), а базу данных в репозитории не хранить

Answer (score 2):

Базу данных я бы порекомендовал хранить не файлом, а скриптом создания. В бинарных файлах крайне сложно отслеживать историю изменений.

А с настройками - при merge чужих изменений делайте `--no-commit` и отменяйте правки вручную. Запретить кому-то править файлы в его копии репозитория в принципе невозможно.