# Что означает «ignored, tracked with git» рядом с именем файла?

Tags: git, phpstorm

[image: ignored, tracked with git]
Перевод я знаю, меня интересует в чём смысл — и игнорируются и отслеживаются одновременно?
Вроде, игнорирую и другие файлы, но они просто серым подсвечены, а рядом с этими эта надпись и они белые, как и остальные отслеживаемые файлы.
Использую «PHPStorm».

Comment: вопрос про программу *phpstorm*, а не про программу *git*. исправил метки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, не уверен, что надо было `git` убирать. Как я понял тут дело в том, что у ТС есть добавленные в индекс файлы, которые потом были добавлены в игнор, но не удалены из индекса. Т.е. дело таки в том как работает gitignore

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, в вопросе просьба объяснить смысл надписи «ignored, tracked with git». эту надпись выдаёт программа *phpstorm* (исходники *git* не «grep-ал», но более чем уверен, что там такой строки нет). потому я считаю, что вопрос именно про эту самую программу.

Comment: Эти файлы были внесены в `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Часто встречается следующая ситуация:

1. Некоторые файлы были сохранены в коммите Git.
2. Потом эти файлы отметили как игнорируемые с помощью `.gitignore` (или `~/.gitignore_global` или [`.git/info/exclude`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/448216/181472)).

В этой ситуации Git [продолжит отслеживать изменения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432432/181472) в файлах, как будто их нет в `.gitignore`. Но пользователи часто думают, что приоритет за `.gitignore` и Git сразу же перестанет «видеть» эти файлы, а то и вовсе удалит их из следующего коммита. Это распространенная ошибка. Среда разработки показывает предупреждение, чтобы помочь заметить и [исправить вероятную ошибку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432895/181472). Слово "ignored" здесь означает не то, что они действительно игнорируются, а что была сделана (неудачная) попытка их игнорировать.

Возможна обратная ситуация: вы случайно «заигнорили» в общем-то нужные файлы. Или вы отлаживаете и экспериментируете с `.gitignore`. Тогда это сообщение поможет вам понять, какие из существующих файлов попали в список игнорируемых.