# Локальный git ignore файл

Tags: git, gitignore

Предположим, лично у меня в проекте есть какие-то файлы, но у других тиммейтов их нет. Как создать личный для меня git ignore с перечислением моих файлов, чтобы добавить его в общий git ignore, вместо того, чтобы добавлять все файлы в общий git ignore?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как игнорировать файлы только в локальном репозитории?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448215/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Если это нужно только в одном проекте, то создайте файл `.git/info/exclude` и в него добавьте список ненужных файлов.

Если это нужно в любом проекте, то файл `~/.config/git/ignore`.